# MS Access - Report to only show items that are out of date/or soon to be

Tags: sql, ms-access

**Context:**

Due to the remote nature of working, the team I work in each have a laptop that they're using for their role (we have thinkpad displaylink units when in the office to connect the laptop to screens). I am working to improve the current allocation records file, which was just a big spreadsheet that you just added a new user to the bottom row. It was messy and hard to read at times, so i've decided to move the data into MS Access and created my data entry and user lookup form, which are working perfectly and make the job easier. I have also been able to make a number of reports that will come in handy too (who has what model ect).

**Query:**

Now the issue is, each of the laptops have a warranty and I am able to produce reports which lists the users and their warranty due date, but this will show all the warranty dates, whether they've been passed or in the future. I want to be able to produce 2 report/queries, the first that will just bring up the laptops who have a warranty that have expired, then another one to bring up those who will expire within the next 6 months so that we can make relevant decisions.

If anyone can assist with this, it will be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply filter criteria to report when opening. Either have parameters in report RecordSource or use code (VBA or macro) to build criteria for OpenReport method WHERE CONDITION argument. Expressions for criteria (ExpireDate is field, substitute with your field name):

1. `[ExpireDate] <= Date()`;
2. `[ExpireDate] BETWEEN Date() AND DateAdd("m", 6, Date())`

Comment: Thankyou for this! My head was spinning for some reason and I was trying to make it more convoluted than it needed to be!